# CSS SVG Wave shape

Tags: css, svg

that's the result I'm trying to achieve

[image]

and here's what I've done: https://codepen.io/demedos/pen/gjQNOM

HTML structure:

```
.container
  .header
  .page-1
    #wave
    #dot
    #text
```

There is some problem though:

- Items are positioned using absolute positioning, while I want them anchored to the main wavy line
- Containers are smaller than their content
- I want the line to be at 50% of the screen, filling the above space with its background color

Comment: @insertusernamehere not really..I don't need to shape a text along a path, but to place elements in a fixed position relatively to the curve (later I will animate it to make the dot 'slide' following the wave)

Comment: You will find it much much easier if you have the "wave", the dot and the text all in the same SVG.  Is that an option?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Yeah it’s totally an option, it’s just that my initial thought was that it would have been easier to animate the dot through the line having different elements, but thinking about it again, element targeting is not that hard. Still I have to fix problem 2 and 3, which is all about positioning at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using a little bit of Javascript.  I've simplified your example to keep things clear.

> I want the line to be at 50% of the screen, filling the above space with its background color

- We use a vertical flex box arrangement to fill the height of the screen.
- We set the `viewBox` to fit the wave curve and let the browser do normal SVG centering.
- We use a very tall wave path and rely on SVG overflowing to make the wave fill to the top of the cell.
- We use `SVGPathElement.getPointAtLength()` to calculate the correct position on the path for each dot.

```js
function positionDot(dotId, fractionAlongWave) {
  // Get a reference to the "wave-curve" path.
  var waveCurve = document.getElementById("wave-curve");
  // Get the length of that path
  var curveLength = waveCurve.getTotalLength();
  // Get the position of a point that is "fractionAlongWave" along that path
  var pointOnCurve = waveCurve.getPointAtLength(curveLength * fractionAlongWave);
  // Update the dot position
  var dot = document.getElementById(dotId);
  dot.setAttribute("cx", pointOnCurve.x);
  dot.setAttribute("cy", pointOnCurve.y);
}


// Position the first dot 25% the way along the curve
positionDot("dot1", 0.25);

// Position the second dot 90% of the way along the curve
positionDot("dot2", 0.90);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 640px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.header {
  background-color: #333835;
}

.page-1 {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.page-1 svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#wave {
  fill:#333835;
}

#dot1,
#dot2 {
  fill:#e05a5a;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
    header 
  </div>
  <div class='page-1'>
    <!-- Set the viewBox to match the curve part of the wave.
         Then we can rely on the browser to centre the SVG (and thus the curve) in the parent container. -->
    <svg viewBox="0 342 1366 283">
      <defs>
        <!-- A copy of the curve part of the wave, which we will use to calculate
             the correct position of the dot using getPointAtLength(). -->
        <path id="wave-curve" d="M0,342c595,0,813,283,1366,283"/>
      </defs>
      <!-- SVGs are "overflow: visible" by default.
           If we make this path extend vertically a long way, it will fill to the
           top of the SVG no matter how high the page is. -->
      <path id="wave" d="M0,342c595,0,813,283,1366,283 V -10000 H 0 Z"/>

      <circle id="dot1" cx="0" cy="0" r="12.5"/>
      <circle id="dot2" cx="0" cy="0" r="12.5"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, excellent explanation. As a side note, I'm trying to make the dot fall and bounce on the line and then roll over it through the end using TweenMax. Any idea on how to use the positionDot to achieve that? Calling it 100 times in a loop seems pretty unefficient

Comment: Move the `getElementById()` and `getTotalLength()` calls out of the loop and you should be fine.

Comment: That's my result: https://codepen.io/demedos/pen/LBMgyr . Did you code the svg shapes by hand? Illustrator seems to create a lot of buzzy code

Comment: Yes. "wave-curve" is just a truncated version of the original path.